# UITextField - capture return button event

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, backspace

How can I detect when a user pressed "return" keyboard button while editing UITextField?
I need to do this in order to dismiss keyboard when user pressed the "return" button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

---

Don't forget to set the delegate in storyboard...

[image]

Comment: Make sure your view controller is set as the textfield's delegate.

Comment: Thank you. For me I set the delegate via `self.yourTextField.delegate = self;`. Even multiple of text fields also work.

Comment: @Praxiteles This can now be done in storyboard without requiring delegation please check answer below.

Answer (score 54):

Delegation is not required, here's a one-liner:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [textField addTarget:textField
                  action:@selector(resignFirstResponder)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
}
```

Sadly you can't directly do this in your Storyboard (you can't connect actions to the control that emits them in Storyboard), but you could do it via an intermediary action.

Comment: I just want to point out that `UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit` event gets sent only if `textFieldShouldReturn:` delegate method returns YES (without prior resigning the text field).

Comment: You don't *have* to implement delegation. But maybe if you do you have to return `YES` for this method.

Comment: You can also use primaryActionTriggered event if you don't want to dismiss the keyboard.

Answer (score 12):

You can now do this is storyboard using the sent event 'Did End On Exit'.

**In your view controller subclass:**

```
 @IBAction func textFieldDidEndOnExit(textField: UITextField) {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

**In your storyboard for the desired textfield:**

[image]

Answer (score 11):

SWIFT 3.0

```
override open func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()    
    textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(enterPressed), for: .editingDidEndOnExit)
}
```

in enterPressed() function put all behaviours you're after

```
func enterPressed(){
    //do something with typed text if needed
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Swift version using UITextFieldDelegate :

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    resignFirstResponder()
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 5**

```
textField.addTarget(textField, action: #selector(resignFirstResponder), for: .editingDidEndOnExit)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)txtField 
{
[txtField resignFirstResponder];
return NO;
}
```

When enter button is clicked then this delegate method is called.you can capture return button from this delegate method.