# Detecting if the keyboard is dragged to dismiss in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have this setting on my table view.:

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
```

I have a notification observer setup like so:

`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)`

My `keyboardWillHide` method is called when the keyboard is finally dragged down and off the screen. Is there a way to detect how the keyboard was dismissed? When `keyBoardWillHide` is called I need to know if it was because the return key was pressed or if the user dragged it so I can tweak animations. Is there any sort of callback for this?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976861/uitextfield-capture-return-button-event

Answer (score 0):

SetUp a variable like:

```
var checker : Bool = false
```

Setting up notification for keyBoardWillHide:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)        
    }
```

Returning keyboard on `Return` key press:

```
 func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            checker = true
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            return true
        }
```

Keyboard will hide selector call:

```
func keyboardWillHide (notif: Notification)
{
    if (checker == true)
    {
        print ("Return key pressed")
    }
    else
    {
        print ("Table dragged down")
    }
    checker = false
}
```

Hope this helps.